# How to burn YouTube videos on a DVD

Tags: dvd, burning

I have downloaded some YouTube videos. They have a `.flv` extension. I want to watch them on my TV with DVD. I burned them onto a DVD using Brasero and XfBurn, but my DVD recorder does not recognize them. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a very easy task. I've googled around, and I found these software:

- [DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html) - recognizes FLV
- [SaveYouTube.com](http://saveyoutube.com/) - you can download videos in MP4, etc... which is recognized by the default DVD writer.

I hope, it helps

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the videos to a format that your DVD recorder / player can recognize. For that you might need a video converter like WinFF
TO install winff , you will need to execute `sudo apt-get install winff` in the terminal

After installing WinFF , fire it up from the dash

1. Click on Add
2. Select your Video
3. On Output Details , Select the Preset your recorder supports from the drop down menu labeled "Convert to" and the preset type.
4. Enter the output Folder , I use /home//Desktop
5. Click on convert , this process should take some time , depending on the video length and other factors.
6. After the video has been converted , you can then burn them to your CD/DVD to play them

Comment: I have installed Winff as you mention. My external DVD player supports files like: MPEG-1, MPEG-2(.VOB/DAT/.MPG) and MPEG-4(.AV1/.DIV/.DIVX) but I do not find them in the drop down menu in Winff. I need to convert mp4 or .flv into them. Can you suggest something? thank's